# Symfony form submit and validate from another method

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony, php-7

I have made a form created after an Ajax request (after the first form (`Test1Type`) is submitted)

```
public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(Test1Type::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $form = $this->createForm(Test2Type::class);

        return new Response($this->renderView('test/_results.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]));
    }

    return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Then I want to submit, validate and get the datas from this `Test2Type` in another method

```
public function confirmAction(Request $request): Response
{
    dump($form->getData());

    return $this->render('test/confirm.html.twig', [
    ]);
}
```

But I don't have acces to my form variable and I will not re-use `$form = $this->createForm(Test2Type::class);`...

I think this is possible but I really don't have any clues to made this work...
Do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, you must create `$form` variable before using it for submittion and validation. To avoid duplicate code on create `Test2Type` form, you should redirect to `confirmAction` in `indexAction` after the form submitted and valid.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(Test1Type::class)->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('confirm.action.route_name');
    }

    return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

public function confirmAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(Test2Type::class)->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        return $this->render('test/confirm.html.twig', [
            'data' => $form->getData()
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('test/_results.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You should add another action in your controller for the ajax request with another route!!

This is better readable code and works better with the history button of your browser. (less cache problems) furthermore you can of course simply change the 'action' attribute of the HTML `<form>` element. Follow this link to read how: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html